# Using sqldf with a list of data frames in R

Tags: r, dataframe, sqldf

I've got a list of data frames which I want to use in an sqldf query. However I don't seem to be able to reference the data frames directly from the list within sqldf either by using $ or [].

my (vastly simplified) code is:

```
DF_List <- list(df1 = data.frame(N = 1:26, N2 = 27:52 ), df2 = data.frame(N = 1:26, L = letters[1:26] ))

sqldf("select * from DF_List$df1, DF_List$df2 where DF_List$df1.N = DF_List$df2.N")
```

The following works - but I want to reference the data frames directly from the list.

```
DF_List <- list(df1 = data.frame(N = 1:26, N2 = 27:52 ), df2 = data.frame(N = 1:26, L = letters[1:26] ))

new_df1 = DF_List$df1
new_df2 = DF_List$df2

sqldf("select * from new_df1, new_df2 where new_df1.N = new_df2.N")
```

Comment: Note that normally one puts the condition in the join: `select * from new_df1 join new_df2 using(N)` ,

Comment: @G.Grothendieck Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `with`

```
with(
  DF_List, 
  sqldf("select * from df1, df2 where df1.N = df2.N"))
```

Or, convert your list to an environment and use the `envir` argument

```
sqldf("select * from df1, df2 where df1.N = df2.N", envir = as.environment(DF_List))
```